# Do I need to explicitly catch and re-throw exceptions when awaiting an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, exception

If I have

```
async function bar() {
  throw 'bar';
}
```

What's the difference between

```
async function foo() {
  await bar();
}
```

and

```
async function foo() {
  try {
    await bar();
  } catch(e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

I heard that I need to explicitly catch and re-throw exceptions inside asynchronous functions, but I assumed `catch(e) { throw e; }` is redundant (if there's no extra processing or logging done before the exception is thrown again).  I believe that's how it is in some other languages; what about JavaScript?

Comment: Can you please include your source that says to do it?

Comment: @4castle It's another developer on my team, but he cited [this article](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await).  I didn't see how the article helps though.

Comment: I don't see where the article says to re-throw the exceptions. And yes, it does nothing to re-throw like that.

Comment: @4castle Me neither.  Here are his exact words: "You need to explicitly catch exceptions at each level or the awaited promise will swallow the error."

Comment: I don't know where he got that information, but it's wrong. It doesn't swallow the error, it returns a rejected promise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to catch and rethrow.  If the expression is a promise that rejects, the expression will throw the value of the rejection.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)